# Computing EC PublicKey from Private Key with BC

Tags: java, android, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve, spongycastle

In my program, I can successfully restore an EC private key from a PEM file using Spongy Castle (Bouncy Castle equivalent for Android). As the file does not contain the public key, I am trying to recompute the public key from the private key.

I am able to compute a valid public key. However, my public key contains much more data (311 bytes) than my original reference (92 bytes). This is even more than the private key (152 bytes).

**How can I get the compressed (?) version of the public key**

```java
PrivateKey privateKey; // private key from pem file
PublicKey referencePublicKey; // public key in my testing environment, generated with an EC KeyPairGenerator


KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC"); // using SpongyCastle provider                     
ECPrivateKeySpec privSpec = factory.getKeySpec(privateKey, ECPrivateKeySpec.class);
ECParameterSpec params = privSpec.getParams();

ECPoint q = params.getG().multiply(privSpec.getD());

ECPublicKeySpec pubSpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(q, params);
PublicKey publicKey = factory.generatePublic(pubSpec);


System.out.println( referencePublicKey.equals(publicKey) );   // true
System.out.println( referencePublicKey.getEncoded().length ); // 92
System.out.println( publicKey.getEncoded().length );          // 311
```

Comment: Any ideas on that?

Comment: What's the problem? Are you are able to verify data with public key? Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37477586/ecc-private-key-is-longer-than-public-key?

Comment: Please post your original key. It's unclear why it's 92 bytes.

Comment: @rustyx Dude, that question is two years old. I don't have the keys I've been testing this with anymore.

Comment: So you don't need an answer anymore?

Comment: I think I somehow worked around this, however, I think it's still worth an answer if you can find one?