# Elliptic Curve PublicKey sharing between different platforms

Tags: .net, swift, encryption, asp.net-web-api, elliptic-curve

I am trying to communicate between android(client), ios(client) and .net(webapi) platforms with Elliptic Curve.

When I try to generate public key on android platform with SpongyCastle, my web api could use this public key. This key's bytes length is 64.

But When I try to generate public key on ios with [SwCrypt](https://github.com/soyersoyer/SwCrypt), my web api couldn't use this key. It throws `IOException - "DER length more than 4 bytes: 119"` . This key's bytes length is 65.

How can I generate Elliptic Curve key pairs on ios platform for communicate with .net web api? Thanks.

Comment: "This key's bytes length is 65." - does it start with 0?

Comment: Also it may be in encoded format. May be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37477586/ecc-private-key-is-longer-than-public-key/37572497#37572497